# How to calculate longest period between two specific dates in SQL?

Tags: oracle, datetime, window-functions, unpivot, gaps-and-islands

I have problem with the task which looks like that I have a table Warehouse containing a list of items that a company has on stock. This
table contains the columns ItemID, ItemTypeID, InTime and OutTime, where InTime (OutTime)
specifies the point in time where a respective item has entered (left) the warehouse. I have to calculate the longest period that the company has gone without an item entering or leaving the warehouse. I am trying to resolve it this way:

```
select MAX(OutTime-InTime) from Warehouse where OutTime is not null
```

Is my understanding correct? Because I believe that it is not ;)

Comment: I think your understanding is incorrect; what you want is a combined list of the combined and sorted `OutTime` and `InTime`, then choose the largest difference between the adjacent pairs. I don't know how to express that in SQL, however...

Comment: (1) Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysq, oracle, sql-server... (2) Sample data and desired result would help clarifying your question

Comment: This can be SQL what I like, lets assume Oracle. The problem is that I do not have sample data and I have to resolve it just thinking on query without any data.

Comment: What exactly is "the longest period that the company has gone without an item entering or leaving the warehouse" supposed to mean? Is this meant per item or general? I.e. is this looking for something like "there was a time when no item got in or out for 100 days" or something like "there was a time when a particular item had no movement for 100 days (while others did have movements at the time)"?

Answer (score 2):

You want the greatest gap between any two consecutive actions (item entering or leaving the warehouse). One method is to unpivot the in and out times to rows, then use `lag()` to get the date of the "previous" action. The final step is aggregation:

```
select max(x_time - lag_x_time) max_time_diff
from warehouse w
cross apply (
    select x_time, lag(x.x_time) over(order by x.x_time) lag_x_time
    from (
        select w.in_time as x_time from dual
        union all select w.out_time from dual
    ) x
) x
```

Comment: While your explanation may be right, your `LAG` is only looking at the two generated rows at a time, thus resulting in `least(in_time, coalesce(out_time, in_time))`. I don't think this is what you intended.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: this does exactly what the description says, that is: identify the greatest gap between *two consecutive actions* (no matter if they are ins or outs,or to which item they relate).. If, for example there are interleaved ins/outs for different items, then they are taken into account.

Comment: Your `LAG` only looks at one original row's in_time and out_time. Thus it does the same as a mere `select max(abs(out_time - in_time)) from warehouse`. Please see this fiddle that hopefully explains this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbd8350e2deaca6965cd9c1bf50aed93

Answer (score 1):

You can directly perform date calculation in oracle.
The result is calculated in days.
If you want to do it in hours, multiply the result by 24.
To calculate the duration in [day], and check all the information in the table:

```
SELECT round((OutTime - InTime)) as periodDay, Warehouse .*  
FROM Warehouse 
WHERE OutTime is not null
ORDER BY periodDay DESC
```

To calculate the duration in [hour]:

```
SELECT round((OutTime - InTime)*24) AS periodHour, Warehouse .*  
FROM Warehouse 
WHERE OutTime is not null
ORDER periodHour DESC
```

round() is used to remove the digits.
Select only the record with maximum period.

```
SELECT *  
FROM Warehouse 
WHERE (OutTime - InTime) = 
( SELECT MAX(OutTime - InTime) FROM Warehouse)
```

Select only the record with maximum period, with the period indicated.

```
SELECT (OutTime - InTime) AS period, Warehouse.*  
FROM Warehouse 
WHERE (OutTime - InTime) = 
( SELECT MAX(OutTime - InTime) FROM Warehouse)
```

When finding the longest period, the condition `where OutTime is null` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has DateDiff, Oracle you can just take one date away from the other.
The code looks ok. Oracle has a live SQL tool where you can test out queries in your browser that should help you.

https://livesql.oracle.com/